# Special case ($3\times 3$ and $4\times 4$) of USAMO 1998 problem #$4$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, contest-math

This is a special case ($3\times 3$ and $4\times 4$) of [USAMO 1998 problem  #4.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2256264/272127)

> A $98\times 98$ chess board has the squares colored alternately black and white in the usual way. A move consists of selecting a rectangular subset of the squares (with boundary parallel to the sides of the board) and switching their colors. What is the smallest number of moves required to make all the squares black?

---

I am trying to obtain optimal moves for $3\times 3$ and $4\times 4$ cases. (I couldn't understand the answers of linked post) I read somewhere that the optimal moves for first one is 2 and for second case is 4. But I tried almost all ways without reaching these numbers. For example for $3\times 3$ one possible solution is as follows:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
\color{red}{1} & 0&1\\
\color{red}{0}&1&0\\
\color{red}{1} & 0&1
\end{bmatrix}\implies \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0&\color{red}{1}\\
1&1&\color{red}{0}\\
0 & 0&\color{red}{1}
\end{bmatrix}\implies \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0&0\\
\color{red}{1}&\color{red}{1}&\color{red}{1}\\
0 & 0&0
\end{bmatrix}\implies \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0&0\\
0&0&0\\
0 & 0&0
\end{bmatrix}$$

which is 3 moves and not 2. What is the best way with 2 moves? and the $4\times 4$ case one possible solution is as follows which is 5 moves:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
\color{red}{1} & 0&1&0\\
\color{red}{0}&1&0&1\\
\color{red}{1} & 0&1&0\\
\color{red}{0}&1&0&1
\end{bmatrix}\implies \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0&\color{red}{1}&0\\
1&1&\color{red}{0}&1\\
0 & 0&\color{red}{1}&0\\
1&1&\color{red}{0}&1
\end{bmatrix}\implies \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0&0&\color{red}{1}\\
1&1&1&\color{red}{0}\\
0 & 0&0&\color{red}{1}\\
1&1&1&\color{red}{0}
\end{bmatrix}\implies \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0&0&0\\
\color{blue}{1}&\color{blue}{1}&\color{blue}{1}&\color{blue}{1}\\
0 & 0&0&0\\
\color{red}{1}&\color{red}{1}&\color{red}{1}&\color{red}{1}
\end{bmatrix}\stackrel{2 rows=2times}{\implies}\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0\\
0 & 0&0&0\\
0 & 0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [1998 USAMO problem #4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2256264/1998-usamo-problem-4)

Comment: The answer is simple No No No. Do you think I am stupid? I have linked that post in my post and you say that "Does this answer your question? "

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGpW0.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the $3\times3$ case you could change two middle rows and get all $1$'s (check that). For the $4\times4$ case the possible sequence of moves is "$3$rd row", "$3$rd column", "$1$st row", "$1$st column".

Comment: what is the middle rows in 3x3?

Comment: Sorry, I mean 2nd row and 2nd column.

Comment: So we should start from middle always?

Comment: In fact, this sequence will work in the general case: you change every second row and every second column. It easy to see that it will produce all 1's, since after you change every second column you will have a picture with the rows of zeros and ones alternating.

Comment: +1. So easy now!! thanks.

Comment: I haven't completed the proof that this is in fact strictly optimal; but I suppose there shall be some invariant which proves it. Let me think for few more minutes:)

Comment: Who down-voted? The Old story! Please please please write your reason.